# Does Hilt provide a way to scope an object to a navigation graph?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, dagger-hilt, jetpack-compose-navigation

I'm using compose navigation in a single activity / zero fragment app. So each screen is a composable. I have a nested graph of screens that represent a flow, lets call it a login flow. There are multiple ViewModels in this flow, and I would like to inject the same instance of LoginRepository into each of these ViewModels.

Is there some kind of `NavGraphComponent` that I can use to inject an instance of LoginRepository that lasts the lifetime of the nav graph? Or does this involve making my own custom component / custom scope?

Comment: U can use `navGraphViewModels` to create View Model instance with sub graph Id .